# Fiddler AutoResponder for many post requests

Tags: http, debugging, fiddler, auto-responder

I'm developing aplication which sends thousands of http post requests. I want to record all responses and use them as stubs with help of Fiddler`.

For example (lets assume product price = productid for simplicity):

1. send request, body`<productId>1</productId>`
2. get real response, body `<productprice>1</productprice>`
3. save response (headers+body) form previous step in local storage,for
   example in some dictionary `[1,"HTTP/1.1 200 OK
   <productprice>1</productprice>"]`. (Since we stored this response,
   next requests matching pattern `body contains
   <productId>1</productId>`should be responded from our local storage
   )
4. send request, body `<productId>1</productId>`
5. load response from local storage and return `HTTP/1.1 200 OK
   <productprice>1</productprice>`
6. send request, body `<productId>2</productId>`
7. get real response, body `<productprice>5</productprice>`
8. save response (headers+body) form previous step in local storage,for
   example in some dictionary `[1,"HTTP/1.1 200 OK
   <productprice>1</productprice>"],[2,"HTTP/1.1 200 OK
   <productprice>2</productprice>"]`
9. ...

How to configure `Fiddler` for it?

Details:

I have already captured 1000  real `POST` requests and i want to debug my application with help of them.

Each request / response is unique and in general looks like:

request

```
POST https://myurl HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer xxx
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8; action="GetList"
Host: myurl.net
Content-Length: 358
Expect: 100-continue 
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <s:Body>
        <catalogRequest xmlns="https://myurl">
            <id xmlns="">1</id>
        </catalogRequest>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ns1="https://myurl">
    <env:Body>
        <ns1:catalogResponse>
            <result>
                <id>1</id>
                <name>some text</name>
                <price>109.99</price>
                ... big xml ...
                <status>1</status>
            </result>
        </ns1:catalogResponse>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

I tried `Autoresponder`, but when i dragged captured sessions to the `Autoresponder` they were converted to rules like: `METHOD:POST EXACT:` - this rule doesn't use POST body. I can't manually change 1000 rules to use `URLWithBody` rule

I think it is possible to create `Fiddler` script, but i don't know how to store captured requests/responses for this script to use them as mapping.

Answer (score 0):

After small research i found a way to record responses and use them as stubs in future. To acheive that i suggest to use fiddler scripts. Here example of scripts in pseudocode

For `BeforeRequest`:

```
var body = session.requestBodyBytes;
var id = GetIdFromBody(body);// code for getting id from request body
session.Reply = id;
```

For `AfterResponse`:

```
var body = session.GetRequestBodyAsString();
var id = GetIdFromRespBody(body);// code for getting id from response body
session.SaveResponse(id);
```

Comment: Can you provide the actual scripts please?

Comment: I had deleted these scripts since i don't need them anymore. But the most important part of such scripts ( is provided in my response) - is that you can get the body of request/response with help of functions: GetRequestBodyAsString, requestBodyBytes @f0rt